# How to create and configure SSL certificate on windows 10 IIS

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

I am doing development on Local host. I need SSL enabled for a module. I have generated Self Signed certificate for it on IIS. But when I run my site it says not secure.
I have even Edited Bindings of the site for Port 443

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html#to-trust-self-signed-certificate

Comment: What version of SSL/TLS.  Only TLS 1.2/1.3 are still being used.  Then you need to use a encryption mode support by 1.2/1.3.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 1):

Try to Secure the server with SSL.

1.In your IIS Manager go to your server -> Scroll down and double-click Server Certificates.

2.Click Import…, you need to import our self signed server certificate in order to enable https communication with SSL.

[image]

3.Your certificate is now added, double-click the newly added cert to verify that it is trusted.

4.Now you can add the https binding, Choose https with port 443, your domain as the host name and find your self signed certificate in the drop down list.
[image]